# Finding $\lim_{t\to 0}(\frac{\sin t}{t})$

Tags: limits

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxWxm.png)
The graph posted is for this: $$\int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$
looking at the behaviour of the graph as $\lim_{t\to 0}$, we can see that the value is $1$. I came across the proofs as to why is it so, but they relied on arc lengths of an unit circle and slight modifications to get the desired result. What confuses me about the limit is how counter-intuitive it is. Going by the standard way of finding limit at a point, if we plug in $t=0$ we get $$\frac{\sin0}{0}=\frac{0}{0}=0$$ But this is not the case, as we have proofs claiming the limit is $1$. Is there an intuitive way to explain this?

Comment: Use that $\sin t = t - t^3/3! + t^5/5!-\dots$

Comment: $\frac{sin(0)}{0} \neq 0$, it is indeterminate. You can use L'Hospital's rule to find the limit

Comment: Going by the standard way, you cannot find the value of that limit. Because $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form and hence not 0. And yes the value is actually 1.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Using L'Hospitals rule does give us the answer but it looks to be another trick to get the result. I guess my question should have been about what exactly indeterminate forms mean intuitively.

Comment: Are you familiar with the squeeze/sandwich theorem?

Comment: @tangentbundle oh yes, about taking two functions  f and h and squeezing g in, that was one of the proofs that I came across. But as I said, the indeterminate form is counter intuitive.

Comment: Note a 100% on this, because I've heard that $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is a special type of function, but you might be able to solve this by doing a taylor series expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be about motivating the limit, and not about the definite integral that inspired your question, so I'll stick to that.

What's "intuitive" varies from person to person, but if you have a mental picture of the graph of $\sin x$ near zero (or trust a device to generate one for you) and compare it to the graph of $x$ near zero (ideally, graph both functions on the same set of axes), the fact that $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ is reflected in the fact that the graphs of $\sin x$ and $x$ become near-indistinguishable the closer $x$ gets to $0$.  If two nonzero numbers are nearly indistinguishable, then their quotient is going to be very close to $1$.  That's what's happening here.  How you justify it depends on the formalism you have or are comfortable with.

Comment: Your explanation does feel intuitive, I'll accept it for that, because that's as close to the intuitive answer I could get. But I see that you are saying $0/0=1$ in just a different way, and not denying $0/0=0$.

Comment: @Cluse A (very) minor variation of leslie townes' answer is: Let $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x.$  Then, $f'(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g'(x) = 1.$  Therefore, as $x \to 0$, two things are true: [1] Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ pass through the point $(x = 0, y = 0).$ [2] Since $\cos(0) = 1, ~f'(x)~$ approaches $g'(x).$ 
This means that as $x \to 0$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will both pass through the same point [i.e. $(x=0,y=0)$] with identical slopes.

Answer (score 1):

This entire topic is very confusing, because of the confusion around the definition of $\sin x$ and $\cos x.$  Since the OP's query makes it clear that (from his perspective) the domain of the sine function (and presumably also the cosine function) is a *dimensionless* number, then there are various choices available for how the sine and cosine function will be defined.

Apostol defines these functions as 2 functions that satisfy the following axioms (if such functions might exist).

- A1 : The sine and cosine functions are defined for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}.$
- A2: $\cos (0) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1, \cos(\pi) = -1.$
- A3: $\cos(y - x) = \cos y \cos x + \sin y \sin x.$
- A4: For $0 < x < \pi/2, ~0 < \cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < \frac{1}{\cos x}.$

Apostol then makes the following points:

- Examination of the traditional sine and cosine functions against the backdrop of the unit circle (centered at the origin) demonstrates that functions that satisfy the axioms do exist, as long as the domain of the functions is construed to be the *dimensionless* length of the corresponding arc (rather than an angle).
- The sine and cosine functions can alternatively be axiomatically defined via the corresponding Taylor series.
- All of the customary theorems around the cosine and sine functions are derivable, based on Apostol's four axioms.

The $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is immediately seen to be $1$, by applying the squeeze theorem to axiom 4.

---

The point of this *rant* is that the issue of how to demonstrate that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ is totally dependent on how the sine and cosine functions are defined.  This means that in Apostol's world, since the derivative of the sine and cosine functions are dependent on his axioms, it would **not** make any sense to attempt to apply L'Hopital's rule to compute the limit.

That would constitute *circular reasoning.*

Comment: Well that's certainly a different way to look at sin and cos. Didn't see it that way. Thanks for your response.