# analytic definition of trigonometric function by means of curve length

Tags: trigonometry, definition

I'm trying to analytically define trigonometric functions following the geometric intuition. To this aim I define the length $\ell(u)\in[0,+\infty]$ of any curve $u$ in $\mathbb R^2$, consider the curve $u(x)=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$ . I define $\pi=\ell(u)$ and prove that $2\le \pi\le 4$. Then I define $\arccos(x)=\ell(u\llcorner[x,1])$ and prove that $\arccos\colon[-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$ is continuos and decreasing so that $\arccos^{-1}\colon [0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ is continuous and decreasing. So we have defined $\cos\colon[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ and can define $\sin=\sqrt{1-\cos^2}$. The functions can then be easily extended to the whole $\mathbb R$.

Now I thought that it should be easy to prove the addition formula for $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$. However it turns out that I'm not able to convert the geometric proof... What I'm missing is a formal definition of rotations by means of the length of curves. The addition formula is in fact equivalent to $R_{\alpha+\beta}=R_\alpha \circ R_\beta$ where $R_\alpha$ is the rotation of angle $\alpha$. I have the curve $v(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ which has the nice property: $\ell(v\llcorner[0,t])=|t|$ and I think I should use this to prove the additivity of rotations... is it doable?

I would like to avoid using derivatives and limits... all the work I described here only uses the $\sup$ operator to define the length of a curve.

Comment: In "Calculus 2nd Ed. Vol 1" (1966), Tom Apostol does something very similar.  He defines the sine and cosine functions as mappings from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ based on a small number of axioms.  Then, he uses these axioms to demonstrate that all of the expected trigonometric identities are implied.  Then, he demonstrates that these *mythical* sine and cosine functions do actually exist.  You simply take the Analytical Geometry definitions, and, for these functions' domains, substitute dimensionless arc lengths along the unit circle in place of *angles*.

Comment: @user2661923 I checked Apostol: he defines the trigonometric functions by means of their series expansion... I'm trying to use a different approach.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059855/finding-lim-t-to-0-frac-sin-tt/4059868?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C20.2744#4059868) for a description of Apostol's definition of the sine and cosine functions, in terms of axioms.  What you are referring to is an alternative approach that defines the sine and cosine functions in terms of the Taylor series.  In the book that I referred to, Apostol uses the approach that I am describing, and merely mentions that the alternative Taylor series approach is possible.